# android when asked for permisions in v4 fragment, activity is closed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

I have the following issue: 
When the user press login button inside a v4 fragment the permission dialog pops up is showed and the fragment content is not visible, and after I accepted the permission the activity is stopped.

The following images are very suggestive:
     [image: initial fragment before to press login]
     [image: after pressing login]
     [image: after accepting the permission]

The code for Manifest is :

```
 <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the-->  
 <uses-permission 

  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

  <!-- To access Google+ APIs: -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

The code for fragment is:

```
package demo.android.checkingforpermission;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements     

        View.OnClickListener {

        private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 101;

        public LoginFragment() {
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup  

        container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, 

                 false);

            //Find the +1 button
            Button login = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.login);
            login.setOnClickListener(this);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.login) {
                checkForLoginPermissions();
            }
        }

        private void checkForLoginPermissions() {
            boolean hasPermission = 

        (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                if (hasPermission) {
                    hasPermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                }

                if (!hasPermission) {
                    requestPermissions(
                            new String[]

                     {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 

                   Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                } else {
                    doShowContacts();
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] 

               permissions, int[] grantResults) {
                if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS  && 

                  grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    doShowContacts();
                }
            }

            private void doShowContacts() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Login ok", 

            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

// The code for activity is:

```
     package demo.android.checkingforpermission;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

        /**
         * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
         */
        public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

            private static final String CURRENT_FRAGMENT = 

              "CURRENT_FRAGMENT";

            private static final String TAG =     
                 LoginActivity.class.toString();

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

                // Check whether the activity is using the layout version 

                   with
                // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add 

                the first fragment
                if (findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {

                    // However, if we're being restored from a previous 

                    state,
                    // then we don't need to do anything and should return 

                       or else
                    // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
                    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = 

                       getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction =  

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.container, new 

                   LoginFragment());
                    transaction.add(R.id.container, new LoginFragment(), 

                     CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
                    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                }
            }
        }
```

// And the xml files are:
   // 1. fragment_login.xml

```
       <FrameLayout 

        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="demo.android.checkingforpermission.LoginFragment">

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        />
    </FrameLayout>

    //and activity_login.xml



      <FrameLayout 

            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".LoginActivity"/>
```

The log file is :

```
09-28 19:36:31.612 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
09-28 19:36:31.612 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
09-28 19:36:31.692 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/android.demo.checkingforpermission-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in android.demo.checkingforpermission rsrc of package android.demo.checkingforpermission
09-28 19:36:31.692 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
09-28 19:36:31.692 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
09-28 19:36:31.702 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
09-28 19:36:31.712 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/android.demo.checkingforpermission-1/lib/arm64
09-28 19:36:31.722 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
09-28 19:36:31.722 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap android.demo.checkingforpermission
09-28 19:36:31.722 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission I/InjectionManager: Constructor android.demo.checkingforpermission, Feature store :{}
09-28 19:36:31.722 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
09-28 19:36:31.742 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/android.demo.checkingforpermission-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in android.demo.checkingforpermission rsrc of package android.demo.checkingforpermission
09-28 19:36:31.742 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/android.demo.checkingforpermission-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in android.demo.checkingforpermission rsrc of package android.demo.checkingforpermission
09-28 19:36:31.782 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
09-28 19:36:31.792 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : android.demo.checkingforpermission.LoginActivity isFragment :false
09-28 19:36:31.812 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
09-28 19:36:31.822 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{37e4ea5 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
09-28 19:36:31.822 8249-8309/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
09-28 19:36:31.872 8249-8309/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
09-28 19:36:31.892 8249-8309/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7fa88df178
09-28 19:36:31.892 8249-8309/android.demo.checkingforpermission I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

                                                                                  [ 09-28 19:36:31.892  8249: 8309 D/         ]
                                                                                  ro.exynos.dss isEnabled: 0
09-28 19:36:31.902 8249-8309/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
09-28 19:36:31.912 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
09-28 19:36:31.922 8249-8309/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : android.demo.checkingforpermission
09-28 19:36:32.052 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@376d83c time:62792654
09-28 19:36:32.262 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1046) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 1046) or=1
09-28 19:36:36.772 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@376d83c time:62797370
09-28 19:36:36.822 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/ViewRootImpl: The input has been finished in ImeInputStage.
09-28 19:36:36.862 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/ViewRootImpl: The input has been finished in ImeInputStage.
09-28 19:36:36.942 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
09-28 19:36:39.742 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
09-28 19:36:39.802 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
09-28 19:36:40.582 8249-8309/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7f92a45400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7fa1c69940
09-28 19:36:40.582 8249-8249/android.demo.checkingforpermission D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
```

Comment: Plase, show the error trace you get.

Comment: i do not have any error but i am posting the log:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i removed the

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

tag from manifest and worked.